# Is Siva's third eye normally hidden?

Tags: shiva, eye

In Siva's iconography, he is mostly depicted with two eyes.  In Tamil, "opening the third (forehead) eye" is a metaphor for becoming extremely angry.

Does Siva manifest the third eye only when needed, like when he burnt Kama?